# Tenant ID setting in case of "startBeforeActivity"

Tags: camunda

ENV: Camunda 7.5

Approach: [Single Process Engine With Tenant-Identifiers](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/multi-tenancy/#single-process-engine-with-tenant-identifiers) with [Transparent Access Restrictions for Tenants](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/multi-tenancy/#transparent-access-restrictions-for-tenants)

Given: `foo` is a process definition key which is deployed without tenant ID, i.e. shared process among all tenants. `bar` is the ID of a service task within `foo`.

The [TenantIdProvider](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/multi-tenancy/#instantiate-a-shared-definition) works well if one start process instances normally (`startXXX` or `startXXXByMessage`). For test cases which don't start process instances this way, rather with:

`runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey('foo')
               .startBeforeActivity('bar')
               .execute()`

the tenant ID doesn't get set. Maybe someone can point out why and how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not implemented yet. See also: https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-6218